# Debug of z-axis-rotation is not 0, while in inspector it is 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the inspector the z-axis rotation of my transform is 0.

But when i debug this using these lines of code:

```
Debug.Log("local-Euler-z: " + transform.localEulerAngles.z);
Debug.Log("global-Euler-z: " + transform.eulerAngles.z);
Debug.Log("local-rot-z: " + transform.localRotation.z);
Debug.Log("global-rot-z: " + transform.rotation.z);
```

you can see in my screenshot that i don't get 0 as value.

[image]

Comment: using (int)transform.localEulerAngles.z is a work-around solution for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, values you're getting are **really** small. `xE+/-y` is an [exponential floating point number representation](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/).

So in reality you have something like this: `6.349661E-05 == 0.00006349661` which is quite close to actual zero.

This problem comes from float numbers precision and because there's actually 2 zeros (-0 & +0) for float numbers in programming - that's just how things work. I don't want to overload this answer, if you want to read something about floats - the link above is a good starting point.

Because of this `float` numbers' problem same number can be represented by close but still different `float` type representation. `float->int` is not really good for cases where you want to compare, let's say, non-int degrees, plus you can't compare `Quaternion` numbers like that - its components `(x, y, z, w)` have values between 0 and 1. To solve this problem you either need to manualy "compare" floats with machine zero which is kinda complicated for a novice, another solution is to use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) from Unity API.

---

By the way, transform inspector shows you pure zero because it just discards such non-affecting digits of the rotation vector.

Comment: @AlpakaJoe, if my answer helped you - please mark it as right answer.