# Countdown timer wont trigger anything when at 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made this countdown timer for my game, and I want it to activate UI when the countdown timer hits 0, but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

here's my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class score : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text ScoreText;

public float scoreAmount;

public int startscore;

private float pointIncreasedPerSecond;

public float scoreMultiplier;

public GameManager gameManager;

void Start()
{
    scoreAmount = startscore;
    pointIncreasedPerSecond = 1f;
}
void Update()
{
    ScoreText.text = scoreAmount.ToString("0");
    scoreAmount += pointIncreasedPerSecond * scoreMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;

    if(scoreAmount == 0)
    {
        gameManager.victory();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't made a countdown timer, you've created a class that holds some data. Nothing in here "counts down"

Comment: Hi @Edmund. 
Probably because scoreAmount isn't exactly 0, but something close to 0. You're working with floating point values. You should set a tolerance for when to trigger the gameManager.victory();. something like if(scoreAmound <= 0.01f){ gameManager.victory(); }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seconds CountDown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191576/seconds-countdown-timer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug of z-axis-rotation is not 0, while in inspector it is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805407/debug-of-z-axis-rotation-is-not-0-while-in-inspector-it-is-0)

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly i assume that your counter starts with a negative value and should increase till 0 right?

So then the `scoreAmount == 0` cannot happen because you are working with floats.

When working with floats (especially with Time.deltaTime) there is almost no chance to get a even number. (Check for `scoreAmount > 0` here)

For future Questions please use the Tags and tell others that you are working with the Unity Engine. No normal programmer will know that `Update()` is called every frame :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
void Start() {
    scoreAmount = the value you want it to be at start
}


void Update() {
    scoreAmount -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (scoreAmount <= 0) {
        gameManager.victory();
    }

}
```

Time.deltaTime is the time from the last frame and every frame we count down and check if the value is less than zero, if yes. the timer finished.
Hope this helped.